# Configure Rider to show ESLint errors/warnings in Errors in Solution tool window

Tags: eslint, jetbrains-ide, rider

ESLint works on opened file just fine with errors/warnings highlighted inside the editor.

However, I want to configure Rider (2020.1) and ESLint to output errors/warnings of all JS/TS files in Rider's Errors in Solution tool window wether files are opened or closed. Is this possible and how?

Comment: There is a whole page on jetbrains site explaining how to do this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/eslint.html#ws_js_eslint_verify_code

Comment: @hendrixchord thx for the link, i will try it. Is it possible to run eslint on all project files and keep watching for any changes to sync warnings/errors in the problem window.

Comment: @handrixchord BTW, there is no Problems tool window in Rider 2020. There is only Errors in Solution which does not show any of ESLint warnings/errors. Any clue?